# Edit Drop-Down List with Json Object

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I have category drop-down list in my project e.g

```
<select name="salescategory_id" id="salescategory_id">
 <option value="">Sales Category</option>
 <option value="1">HPC</option>
 <option value="2">BTY</option>
 <option value="3">GRO</option>
 <option value="4">OTH</option>
 </select>
```

I have to edit this list with json. I am using the following approach to edit this list and other form fields:

```
function editamazonresearch(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url: '<?php echo SITE_URL;?>products/list/' + id, 
        success: function(data){ 

            $("#title").val(json_data_object.data.amazontitle);
            options = '<option value="' + json_data_object.Salecategory.id + '">' + json_data_object.Salecategory.salescategory + '</option>';
            $("select#salescategory_id").html(options);

            $("#usercomment").val(json_data_object.data.usercomment);           
        } 
    }); 
}
```

But this line of code doesn't give me the desire out put as it removes other option values while editing.

Comment: That's because you're overwriting them when you call `.html()`, use `.append()` instead

Answer (score 1):

From your javascript it doesn't appear that you are looping over a list of products and adding anything.

You are just replacing the content of the `select#salescategory_id` with the `options` string

From your question I would expect something more like

```
$.each(data, function(k, v) {
    option = '<option value="' + v.Salecategory.id + '">' + v.Salecategory.salescategory + '</option>';
    $("select#salescategory_id").append(option);
});
```

in your `success` method

**But** without knowing the data structure of the response to your ajax call, its very hard to guess at what you are trying to do